# Django queryset with multiple M2M?

Tags: python, django

```
class Node(models.Model):
    # ...  

class Zone(models.Model):
    nodes = models.ManyToManyField(Node)

class BusLine(models.Model):
    zones = models.ManyToManyField(Zone)

class Service(models.Model):
    bus_lines = models.ManyToManyField(BusLine)
```

How can I get all the nodes related to the zones that are related to the buslines that are related to ONE service?

Answer (score 0):

```
Node.objects.filter(zone__busline__service=my_service)
```